# blank page after deploying Laravel app to AWS using serverless

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, serverless-framework

I have a project in laravel it work fine in my local, Then I am learning how to deploy it to laravel using serverless but when I deployed it, shows a blank page:
This is what I have done:

```
composer require bref/bref bref/laravel-bridge
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=serverless-config
```

Then it creates the yml file:

**serverless.yml**

```
service: laravel

provider:
    name: aws
    # The AWS region in which to deploy (us-east-1 is the default)
    region: us-east-1
    # The stage of the application, e.g. dev, production, staging… ('dev' is the default)
    stage: dev
    runtime: provided.al2

package:
    # Directories to exclude from deployment
    exclude:
        - node_modules/**
        - public/storage        
        - storage/**
        - tests/**        

functions:
    # This function runs the Laravel website/API
    web:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-74-fpm}
        events:
            -   httpApi: '*'
    # This function lets us run artisan commands in Lambda
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-74} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer

plugins:
    # We need to include the Bref plugin
    - ./vendor/bref/bref
```

In the documentation says this:
*By default, the Laravel-Bref package will automatically configure Laravel to work on AWS Lambda*

Then I run this commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
serverless deploy
```

Then it says that everything was ok and displays the endpoint:

ANY - https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

The laravel project displays a blank page, then I inspected the code, it had this:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>  

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/js/app.js" defer=""></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">     
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

</body></html>
```

Then I copied the js url:
https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/js/app.js
pasted in the browser and it displays the same blank page!!

After that I created a new bucket , made it public and added some policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1615766544442",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1615766541336",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Run these commands:

```
npm run prod
aws s3 sync public/ s3://bucket-name/ --delete --exclude index.php
```

added this to the .env file:

MIX_ASSET_URL=https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com
And just in case I created a new enviroment variable in the lambda function with the same values

Then deploy it again:

```
serverless deploy
```

But again it displays the same blank page. it looks the js an css are not being uploaded properly.
What is going it? thank you.

Comment: That URL is the URL of your API Gateway endpoint, not your site. Your site, including its index, will be in an S3 static hosting location.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I saw the s3 bucket was created, what should be the next step to get the url for the website?

Comment: Ah, actually [it looks like](https://bref.sh/docs/first-steps.html) bref doesn't deploy assets to S3, instead it serves them from the Lambda function itself behind API Gateway, so you were right to hit the API Gateway endpoint. You're going to have to do a little debugging: view source of the page, check browser console logs, check browser network capture, and maybe check the Lambda function's logs (in CloudWatch Logs). Start in the browser: did you get an HTML page from the URL? What does the browser show in console and network?

Comment: I was able to get an HTML, in the question is the HTML that I got. the problem is the css and js, those are not loaded properly. When I hit the js directly, for example:  https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/js/app.js it displays the same HTML. In my local file: resources/views/layouts/app.blade I have this for the js :  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> So I think that the asset() is the problem. In the console log I got this: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'  in app.js

Comment: Probably worth reading the [assets](https://bref.sh/docs/runtimes/http.html) doc and the [Creating serverless PHP websites](https://bref.sh/docs/websites.html) doc.